# Jquery get Name value of hidden field

Tags: jquery, hidden

I am trying to get the value from the name in a hidden field. The name / value is created dynamically. The ID column is created sequentially. 
here is the HTML

```
<div="campAddons">

<input type="hidden" id="column2" name="Housing" value="108">

<div>
```

here is my jquery

```
column1Name = $("#campAddons input[id='column2']").val(name);
console.log(column1Name);
```

i keep getting object.object in the console log.

Comment: since IDs should be unique, `$("#column2")` will suffice to target the imput

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name is an attribute. So you have to use `.attr()` to get its value. Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to learn more about it.

Try,

```
column1Name = $("#campAddons input[id='column2']").attr('name');
console.log(column1Name);
```

OR

```
column1Name = $("#column2").attr('name');
console.log(column1Name);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/vugSc/)